# modify event data during propagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Is there any way of attaching data to a jQuery event object as it propagates up the DOM?

To clarify, if you have three nested divs, each with a click event listener, then clicking on the innermost div results in all three handlers being called from the innermost to the outermost (event propagation 101). What I'd like to do is add some data to the event object in each handler that's accessible to the next layer up.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I've misunderstood the question, but I came across this StackOverflow page whilst searching for a way to do the same thing.

I have since found that you can return the value/values that you want to pass at the end of each handler and then access them in subsequent handlers using the `event.result` property?

Simple demo at http://api.jquery.com/event.result/

Comment: I don't believe this is the correct answer. It's not working for me after the event has bubbled higher up the DOM.

Answer (score 43):

The event object that is passed by jQuery is a wrapper around the native event object. The bubbling happens at the javascript/browser level and hence the native event object seems to be shared among all the event handlers.

```
$('div').click(function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.attribute =  (e.originalEvent.attribute || "") + 
        " " + $(this).prop("className");
    alert(e.originalEvent.attribute);
});
```

Tested in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE9 and IE10. If you test in other browsers please comment with the results.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5AQqD/

Comment: I just tested this on IE10/9 and it works. This should be the correct solution.

Comment: bummer, no IE8 support.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you. This should really be documented on MDN.

Comment: this will break the js if the event was triggered with javascript (originalEvent will be undefined).

Comment: @nils every object in JavaScript is an `expando` object, i.e. you can attached anything to it as you please. This is not a feature of the event system but of JavaScript that can be used in this particular way.

Comment: This solution works great, especially if you have intercepting handlers.

Comment: This is extremely useful. My use case involves needing to "cancel" an event higher up in the bubble, but I didn't want to use stopPropagation because it can interfere with other APIs.

Answer (score 5):

Although you cannot attach data directly to the event, you could still attach data to the `targetElement` via jQuery's `data()`:

```
$('div').click(function(e) {
    var info = $(e.target).data('info') || '';
    $(e.target).data('info', info + ' ' + $(this).attr('class'));
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eKVmU/

Comment: This solution works the first time the event is fired, but the data persists through multiple events (on the jsfiddle, try clicking multiple times and see what happens).  Would really love a way of associating data with a specific click as it bubbles up, as opposed to a specific element...

Comment: @josh - Why don't you just remove the data when it hits the outermost element? [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/eKVmU/7/).

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't answer the question asked by the OP: "attaching data to a jQuery event object". The second highest voted answer does just that and should be on top, and the accepted answer...

Comment: Agreed that this is not the ideal solution - modifying the originalEvent should be the accepted answer