# jquery event data on bubble up

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [modify event data during propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117935/modify-event-data-during-propagation)

Is there a way to pass a value from one event handler to another in the stack (while the event is bubbling up)?

I know that I can use .on() to set a event.data map - but how can I add to that and pass it up the event handler chain?

Answer (score -1):

`$("button").eq(i).on("click", {value: 'customData'}, function(event) {});`

This way you can specify a new variable `value` into the `data` object.

Access: `event.data.value`