# Can I configure Mapbox GL JS to do the dragRotate behavior without the shift key?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'd like to make a map that is fixed on a specific point (`options.dragPan=false`), but allows the user to rotate and pitch the map with their mouse. I can ask users to hold the ctrl key down while they drag the mouse (or use the right mouse button), but I'd prefer to configure the map such that the shift key is unnecessary.

Is there a good way to hijack the `mousemove` event to achieve this? Maybe [modify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18319002/1811952) e.ctrlKey before it propogates to the mapbox handler?

For reference: [the DragRotateHandler class](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/master/src/ui/handler/drag_rotate.js#L24-L343)

Comment: It doesn't look like the event modifications are propagated: http://jsfiddle.net/58c6qgyh/1/